# problem programmatically adding a tapGesture

Tags: forms, xamarin, visual-studio-2019

Can anyone help me with the following code example I am working on?

```
for (int newCol = 0; newCol <= MaxCols; newCol++)
{
    for (int newRow = 0; newRow <= MaxRows / MaxCols; newRow++)
    {
        if (folderIndex >= DirectoryArrayList.Count) { break; }
        var folder = DirectoryArrayList[folderIndex];
        var label = new Label()
        {
            Text = folder.Name,
            FontSize = 12,
            VerticalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,
            HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center
        };
        var GridBox = new BoxView() { BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#1ceaea") };
        var GridImage = new Image() { Source = "folder.png", StyleId= "Image"};
        var GridTap = new TapGestureRecognizer();
        GridTap.Tapped += async (sender, e) =>
        {
            string selectedFolder = MainFolder + folder.Name; // Will normally be a propertie stored in an array.
            if (Directory.Exists(selectedFolder))
            {
                //lstProperties.ItemsSource = selectedFolder; // Actual output purpose...
                await DisplayAlert("Folder", selectedFolder, "OK").ConfigureAwait(false); // Debug purposes...
                Console.WriteLine(selectedFolder); // Debug purposes...
            };
        };
        GridImage.GestureRecognizers.Add(GridTap);
        GridFolders.Children.Add(GridBox, newCol, newRow);
        GridFolders.Children.Add(GridImage, newCol, newRow);
        GridFolders.Children.Add(label, newCol, newRow);
        folderIndex += 1;
    }
}
```

I have created a GridTap var that should react to a tap gesture when a user clicks on that particular GridImage, for some reason it dos not work! I am assuming that it may be a problem with each image not having a unique name/Id, but I cannot find a way of implicating it.

The general idea is to have a grid element that has a click event, and the folder that the grid element resembles will be opend, but this is the only way I have found so far that slightly resembles what I want to do

Comment: you are adding three elements to each cell, so only the "top" element (the one added last) will respond to gestures.  Try adding the label before the image.

Comment: No luck there, the label goes behind the image, and still no click event happens!

Comment: Even if I add only the GridImage it doesn't react to the click event.

Comment: how are you testing?  Are you using the debugger, or just observing the behavior of the app?  I'd also try using a handler as opposed to an anonymous delegate

Comment: GridBox, GridImage and label, aen't they supose to be part of the same layout? so like Jason said, you are adding 3 diferent elements to each cell, andthe top one will catch the gesture, you should wrap everything into one Layout, and that layout should have your gesture recognizer

Comment: Yes they should be part of the same layout, thank you for that point, what is the best aproach for this? StackLayout?. I did some testing without the if Directory.Exists part and I get a click event on the first 2 folders, these being .__override__ and .Local, the other folders ... TestFolder1 and TestFolder2 do not give an event.

Comment: again, are you using a breakpoint in the debugger to test this?  If not are just testing based on observation, then it may not be the gesture recognizer that is the problem

Comment: @Mark i based my anwser on the premise that the problem was from the GestureRecognizer, and not from the code itself.. you need a little more focus on what is the real problem, from what you said, the gesture recognizer was already working, but not the function inside it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are Adding 3 diferent Layouts into the same Row and Column, the element that will be on top will catch your GestureRecognizer, i suggest you wrap everything into a layout, pass the GR to that layout, and then add it to your GridFolders, something like this:

```
var GridTap = new TapGestureRecognizer();
GridTap.Tapped += async (sender, e) =>
{
    ...
};
StackLayout LayoutToReceiveTheGesture = new StackLayout();
StackLayout.GestureRecognizers.Add(GridTap);
StackLayout.Children.Add(GridBox);
StackLayout.Children.Add(GridImage);
StackLayout.Children.Add(label);
GridFolders.Children.Add(GridBox, newCol, newRow);
```

Comment: Hi, I have mannaged to achieve this using your code example with a slight change ... '           var Layout = new StackLayout();
                            //Layout.Children.Add(GridBox);
                            Layout.Children.Add(GridImage);
                            Layout.Children.Add(label);
                            Layout.GestureRecognizers.Add(GridTap);
                            GridFolders.Children.Add(Layout, newCol, newRow); ' thanj you for your guidence :-) There is another problem that has now been brought to light, and it lies someone where within the grid layout.

Comment: @Mark yes i already added that edit, i noticed i was including the Rows and Columns inside the StackLayout, if it worked then Marked as the correct anwser and maybe an upvote :)

Comment: dam my timing :-)

Comment: Ok found the other problem,In xmal, I had a grid within a grid within a stack layout, thats the reason why I could only get a click event from the first column...Still working on it, again thank you all for your support in my learning progress :-)